# Surface integral of $f(x) = \frac{1}{ \Vert x -x_0 \Vert } $ over sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, surface-integrals, multiple-integral

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ the sphere of radius $r$ centered at the origin. Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be such that $x_0 \notin S $.

Let $f:S \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{ \Vert x -x_0 \Vert }. $

Calculate the surface integral
$$ \int_S f \Vert dσ \Vert$$.

The parametrization of the sphere is given by

$$ σ(x,y) = r( \cos(x) \sin(y) , \sin(x) \sin(y), \cos(y)).$$

Developing the definition of the integral I get that I have to find:

$$ \int_{[0,2π] \times [0,π]}   \dfrac{r^2 sen(y)}{\Vert σ(x,y) - x_0 \Vert}.$$ Now, I don't know how to solve the last integral. I think I'm supposed to use Gauss theorem, but I can't find a way to express it as the integral of a differentiable vector function.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037974/surface-integral-over-a-sphere-of-inverse-of-distance

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042840/surface-integral-for-a-point-inside-or-outside-of-sphere?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

The case $\lVert\mathbf{x}_0\rVert=0$ is just integrating a constant, so let's assume $\lVert\mathbf{x}_0\rVert>0$.

Choosing spherical polar coordinates with the $\mathbf{x}_0$-direction being the zenith (equivalently, use a rotation to put $\mathbf{x}_0$ on the positive $z$-axis and use the usual spherical polars) the required integral becomes
\begin{align*}
\int_Sf\,\mathrm{d}S
&=2\pi\int_0^\pi\frac{r^2\sin\theta}{\sqrt{r^2+\lVert\mathbf{x}_0\rVert^2-2r\,\lVert\mathbf{x}_0\rVert\cos\theta}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=2\pi \frac{r}{\lVert\mathbf{x}_0\rVert}\left[\sqrt{r^2+\lVert\mathbf{x}_0\rVert^2-2r\,\lVert\mathbf{x}_0\rVert\cos\theta}\right]_0^\pi\\
&=\frac{2\pi r[(r+\lVert\mathbf{x}_0\rVert)-\lvert r-\lVert\mathbf{x}_0\rVert\rvert]}{\lVert\mathbf{x}_0\rVert}\\
&=\begin{cases}
4\pi r & \lVert\mathbf{x}_0\rVert<r\\
\dfrac{4\pi r^2}{\lVert\mathbf{x}_0\rVert} & \lVert\mathbf{x}_0\rVert>r
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: Isn't this the potential of a charged spherical shell with uniform charge density?  Shouldn't the answer for $\mathbf{x}_0$ in the exterior of $S$ be $4\pi r^2/\|\mathbf{x}_0\|$ which would agree with Gauss' law (and the duplicate answer)?

Comment: Oops, yes, there should be a modulus sign.